# Receiving empty model in Controller using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

View:

```
 $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(form.serialize()),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) { },
        });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(ContactUsModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

I am receiving empty values in model.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your model and your form?

Answer (score 2):

If you're posting a form you don't need to stringify it. Remove `JSON.stringify`.

```
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {                           
    },
   });
```

[`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) already serializes your form into a string that .NET will be able to parse into a model, as long as the form contains the necessary values for the model.

Also, as Stephen mentioned, you shouldn't set `application/json` as `contentType` since it's passed as an urlencoded form. Use the [default](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, by not setting it at all.

Comment: You also need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (it has to use the default - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`)